# ajax modalpopupextender with firefox 3.6 gets displayed on the bottom of page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have a modalpopup extender that works on IE (8) and does not work on FF

I have searched google for hours but I could not find a solution yet.

I do have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

at the start of the page.

And this is the modalpopupextender :

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modal2" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="divAddNewRows" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="OkButton" OnOkScript="onOk()" CancelControlID="CancelButton" BehaviorID="modal2" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="divAddNewRows" />
```

And this is the div on the same page:

```
<div id="divAddNewRows" style="display: none;" class="modalPopup" enableviewstate="false">
```

This is the css :

```
.modalPopup {
```

/*background-color:#ffffdd;*/
 background-color:White;
 border-width:3px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:Black;
 padding:3px;
 width:670px;

}

The code is using javascript to make a call to this and it does .show() like this :

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
```

if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
   if (xmlHttp.responseText.length > 0) {
       var div = $("div[id$=divAddNewRows]")[0];      //document.getElementById('divAddNewRows');
    div.style.display = '';
    div.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    //use popupmodal extender to display
    $find("modal2").show();

```
// default to first textbox, if we can. 
try {
 $("#savefield0")[0].focus();
}
catch (err) {
 // do nothing
 var noop = err;
}
```

}
  }
 }
 else {
  //alert("An error has occurred, please try again later. If the problem persists please contact support and quote error code 3, status code" + xmlHttp.status);
 }

Before the first 'if' it will call xmlhttpobject and this works fine.

Can someone please give me a hand on this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gave up on this. Using jQuery instead.